# Can I migrate an single-AZ RDS instance from db.t2.micro to db.t4g.micro without any issues?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

AWS has notified that they will discontinue M4, R4, and T2 type database instances. Well, I have a single-AZ RDS instance of type db.t2.micro running MySQL 8.0.35.

I'm thinking of upgrading the database instance to db.t4g.micro because it's slightly cheaper than db.t3.micro.
[image: Single-AZ RDS instance pricing table]

So, I'd like to hear from the community what you guys think, could this switch cause any issues since the t3 line has x86 architecture while the t4g architecture is ARM-based?

I appreciate your attention in advance!

Comment: I recommend creating a new instance from a snapshot and trying it out. But given that the difference in price is under $9/year, is that even worthwhile? (at least until AWS deprecates db.t3).